# Generating A_n using involutions -- minimum number of multiplications that are sufficient?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

What is the smallest $k = k(n)$ for which the following holds?

There is a set of involutions $I \subset A_n$ such that for every $a \in A_n$, there exist $i_1, \ldots, i_k \in I$ such that $i_1 i_2 \cdots i_k = a$.

More generally, is there common terminology for the study of such questions?  I.e., where one is not minimizing the size of the generating set, but rather minimizing the number of multiplications necessary to produce any element (of course some restriction on the generating set, e.g. only involutions, is necessary to make this question non-trivial).

Comment: In general, if a group is generated by $X$, then the smallest $k$ such that every $g \in G$ is a product of words of length at most $k$ in $X \cup X^{-1}$ is the diameter of the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $S$. It is hard to compute in general . It has only recently been done for the Rubik's Cube group. In your question, you might as well take $I$ to be the set of all involutions in $A_n$. $k(5)=k(6)=2$, $k(7)=k(8)=k(9)=3$, $k(10)=2$, $k(11)=k(12)=k(13)=3$, $k(14)=2$. That's as far as I can go with naive computation, but it suggests a pattern!

Comment: I think it is not hard to prove the pattern suggested by Derek Holt, using the fact that each element of the group $S_n$ is a product of independent cycles (and the respective characterizations of the elements of $A_n$) and, possibly, also using induction.